# How can I prevent column A from being almost completely hidden in a Report Services report when it is exported to Excel?

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, multiple-columns, rdl

I am making some changes to a legacy report (read: not created by me or anyone still here), and one of the requirements is to "Unhide Column A"

And yes, when I run the report and export it to Excel, column A is *almost* completely obscured:

[image]

When I expand it, it contains no data of its own. Why and how it is being "mostly hidden" this way, I don't know.

But it apparently confuses or irritates the users that the first usable column is "B"

How can I get column A to display without moving the contents on the sheet to the right? IOW, I basically want to display column A but move all the data one row to the left (what's in Column B should be in Column A, what's in column C should be in column B, etc.)

Here is how it looks after expanding column A:

[image]

This is what they want it to look like (after a manual tweaking of the sheet):

[image]

Comment: How do you get 10k points and 50 gold badges and not show any effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to move the logo in the report all the way to the left. The export to Excel tries to match the layout as closely as it can. Any gaps, or mismatched widths between images and table columns will come out looking pretty rough in Excel if things aren't lined up perfectly. You can have merged cells all over the place if you aren't precise with image placement.

I always try to make sure the image I use is in the upper left corner, with no margin, and the first column in my tablix, or matrix, is the same width as the image. Sometimes it ends up being a few columns that all together match the width of the image. Just as long as they line up, the export should look pretty good.

Making these all align can be a bit of a pain. Use the blue alignment indicators that show in the designer to help yourself out. Some times I have to go into the properties and adjust widths and height manually.

If it isn't the image then something else in the report needs alignment.

All this... or just give it to them in a PDF!! ;)

Comment: By "All they way to the left" do you mean a location.left value of "0in"?

Comment: That is correct. Leave no gaps between the edge of the report and the image.